# Multicolumn table with wrapping

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a multicolumn table, with the column heading split in to two lines and each column has two subcolumns (except the first one). It is not working. Any help ?

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Optimal R (in \%).\\Options: T for threshold, CS for cost-sensitive and CS{\small \&}T for hybrid. }
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.15cm}
  \begin{tabular}{|l*{16}{c}|}
    \hline
    {Baseline \\ Options}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SVP\\ --} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV \\ \sc t} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV\\ \sc cs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV\\ \sc t} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV \\ \sc cs{\scriptsize \&}t} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV \\ \sc t} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV \\ \sc cs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV \\ \sc cs{\scriptsize \&}t} \\
        & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
    \hline
        & & & & & & & & & &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    Ad    & 67.3 & 67.3 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 \\
    \hline 
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:tab_bin_post}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `multicol` package is completely wrong for a `multicolumn` table. Please don't use such outdated commands such as `\sc` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line breaks do not work in `l` or `c` columns. You would need `p` columns or nested `tabular`s. The following example just makes a second line for the second line of the table header.

Also the table is much too large for a normal portrait page, thus I rotated it via package `rotating` and environment `sidewaystable`.

And package `booktabs` is used for better lines and proper spacing around the lines:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption[Optimal R (in \%)]{%
    Optimal R (in \%).\\
    Options: T for threshold, CS for
    cost-sensitive and CS{\small \&}T for hybrid.}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.15cm}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{16}{c}}
    \toprule
    Baseline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SVP}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SV} \\
    Options
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{--}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape t}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape cs}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape t}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape cs{\scriptsize\&}t}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape t}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape cs}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scshape cs{\scriptsize\&}t}
    \\
    & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2
    \\
    \midrule
    Ad    & 67.3 & 67.3 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9
    & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:tab_bin_post}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a paper size of A4 or US-Letter and horizontal margins of 1", it is just (but only just!) possible to squeeze the table into the text block, *if* you reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` suitably. I suggest that you use a `tabular*` environment, set its width to `\textwidth`, and let LaTeX handle the tedious chore of figuring out the amount of intercolumn whitespace needed to make the table occupy the intended width.

I further suggest you (i) use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, (ii) simplify the table header by providing a *single* "SV" header for columns 4 through 17, (iii) use `\cmidrule` instructions judiciously to provide further visual structure to the material in the table's header, and (iv) place some of the material that's currently in the argument of the `\caption` command *below* the caption itself. Finally, don't use the instruction `\sc` in a LaTeX document. Instead, use either `\textsc{...}` or `{\scshape ...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in, letterpaper]{geometry} % choose margins here
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}    % handy utility macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Optimal R (in \%)} \label{tab:tab_bin_post}

  Options: \textsc{t} for threshold, 
           \textsc{cs} for cost-sensitive, and 
           \textsc{cs{\scriptsize \&}t} for hybrid.

  \medskip
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1mm} % let LaTeX figure out nec. amount of intercol. whitespace
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{16}{c}}
    \toprule
    Baseline  & \mc{SVP} & \multicolumn{14}{c}{SV}\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule{4-17}
    Options & \mc{--}
    & \mc{\scshape t} & \mc{\scshape cs} 
    & \mc{\scshape t }& \mc{\scshape cs{\scriptsize \&}t} 
    & \mc{\scshape t} & \mc{\scshape cs} 
    & \mc{\scshape cs{\scriptsize \&}t} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
    \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13} \cmidrule{14-15} \cmidrule{16-17} 
        & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 
        & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2  \\
    \midrule
    Ad    & 67.3 & 67.3 & 67.9 & 67.9 
          & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 
          & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 
          & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9 & 67.9   \\
    \bottomrule 
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would love to accept both as answers, but SE does not allow that. Your answer very much helpful and cleared more doubts than the question